# Java RegEx for CSV List of 5 to 11 digit numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java Regex to capture a single number that is 5 to 11 digits in length:

```
^[0-9]{5,11}$
```

I also need to be able to capture a CSV list of inputs with the same number format.  An example of this input would be something like:

```
 0123456789,012345,012345678,01234567890
```

How can I expand the earlier RegEx to capture the additional comma-separated values?

Comment: Remove the start- and end-string ancors?

Comment: @JvdV then it will match numbers longer than 11 digits. Some anchoring (to the commas, to the string start and end) has to be there.

Comment: @Realskeptic, I guess that's true =)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
^[0-9]{5,11}(?:,[0-9]{5,11})*$
```

Where:

- `(?:,[0-9]{5,11})*` matches 0 or more times a number with 5 to 11 digits, preceded by a comma

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/plSxbq/1)

Answer (score 1):

Just have a second optional group that has a comma in it. Try:

```
^[0-9]{5,11}(,[0-9]{5,11})*$
```